# Display Escape Sequence (Single or Double Quote) in apex:outputText

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to display US State inside single quote in Visualforce page. Please find below the visualforce page code where tax rate is param {0}
and US State name is param {1}.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(Tax__c.Rate=='0','No state tax applied','Tax rate is {0} percent for state {1}')}">
   <apex:param value="{!Tax__c.Rate}"/>
   <apex:param value="{!Tax__c.StateName}"/>                       
</apex:outputText>
```

I tried using \' before param {1}--that is `'Tax rate is {0} percent for state \'{1}'\'`. But it is not working and displaying \ instead of '.
Do you have any solution to display single quote or double quote in apex:outputText in Visualforce page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally put the quotes in the parameter, instead:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(Tax__c.Rate=='0','No state tax applied','Tax rate is {0} percent for state {1}')}">
   <apex:param value="{!Tax__c.Rate}"/>
   <apex:param value="'{!Tax__c.StateName}'"/>                       
</apex:outputText>
```

This is probably the least painful method of getting this to work. Normally, in an apex:outputText, you can use `''` to force a single `'`, but within an expression, it becomes apparently impossible.

Answer (score 2):

In a pinch, sometimes I just declare a variable (sq for single quote) to avoid making the syntax messier.

```
<apex:variable value="'" var="sq" />

<apex:outputText value="{!IF(Tax__c.Rate=='0','No state tax applied','Tax rate is {0} percent for state '+sq+'{1}'+sq)}">
   <apex:param value="{!Tax__c.Rate}"/>
   <apex:param value="{!Tax__c.StateName}"/>                       
</apex:outputText>
```

You could similarly do:

```
<apex:variable value='"' var='dq' />
```

Comment: +1, but this technique has potential drawbacks if you do this inside a component or a page destined to be included into other pages.

Comment: This is true - I've run into the clashing variable situation I assume you're alluding to. If your page or component has its own Apex controller you could also just make sq/dq controller variables.